# ¿Como puedo leer todos los xml que se encuentran en una carpeta?

Tags: html, python, flask

Previamente estoy usando **xmltodict** para leer xml uno por uno desde Flask en un ambiente web Utilizando python.
Lo que quiero hacer es seleccionar una carpeta y que todos los xml que ahí estén los pueda leer y a cada uno sacarle un código que me interesa y listar el nombre del archivo mas las claves. 
La parte de consultar lo que me interesa del xml ya esta, solo quiero ver lo de leer varios xml de una carpeta que yo pueda seleccionar.

Mi código es este para leer el xml desde HTML

```
<form id="formxml" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Seleccionar xml</label>
      <input type="file" name="archivo" accept=".xml" class="form-control-file" id="archivo_xml" multiple="" required>
      <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Input" id= "btn">
    </div>
  </form>
```

y el código de python para recorrer el xml es el siguiente

```
import os
import sys
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
import xmltodict
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'

@app.route("/")
def upload_file():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route("/uploader", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == "POST": 
        xml_r = request.files['archivo']
        todo = xmltodict.parse(xml_r)
return todo


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `os.walk()` para recuperar los ficheros en un directorio concreto. Por ejemplo:

```
import os

path = 'c:\\ruta\\a\\tu\\carpeta\\'

# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.xml' in file:
            with open(file) as fichero:
                x = fichero.read()
                # en x tienes ahora el xml que estaba dentro del fichero
```